# Problems while trying to make a query using left join and group by with having over a field of the left table on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im trying to make some queries, first, I do this one (and works):

```
SELECT RP.id, RP.product_name, RP.price, RP.retailer_id, RP.product_id, 
count(G.id) AS duration, G.active, RP.retprod_id, P.pr_id AS video 
FROM retailer_products AS RP 
LEFT JOIN groups G ON RP.id=G.retailer_product_id 
INNER JOIN products P ON P.id=RP.product_id 
WHERE (RP.product_id IN (1)) 
GROUP BY RP.id;
```

But when I do this one, it gaves me an empty set, the difference is that it has a "HAVING" at the end of the query over a field that may be: 0, 1 or NULL (because of the LEFT JOIN, I have no groups linked to the table retailer_product)

```
SELECT RP.id, RP.product_name, RP.price, RP.retailer_id, RP.product_id, 
count(G.id) AS duration, G.active, RP.retprod_id, P.pr_id AS video 
FROM retailer_products AS RP 
LEFT JOIN groups G ON RP.id=G.retailer_product_id 
INNER JOIN products P ON P.id=RP.product_id 
WHERE (RP.product_id IN (1)) 
GROUP BY RP.id HAVING G.active=1;
```

So, I tried the following ways but no one works:

```
-- HAVING G.active=1

-- HAVING G.active=1 OR G.active=NULL

-- HAVING G.active0
```

What is the right way to handle this on MySQL? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to compare value with `NULL` is `IS NULL`. So you need to add `HAVING G.active IS NULL OR G.active=1`.   Your code `G.active=NULL` is always `NULL` (false):

```
1 = NULL // NULL - false in conditions
NULL = NULL // NULL - false in conditions
NULL IS NULL // TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't add the HAVING condition on the "Group" ON condition?

```
SELECT RP.id, RP.product_name, RP.price, RP.retailer_id, RP.product_id, 
count(G.id) AS duration, G.active, RP.retprod_id, P.pr_id AS video 
FROM retailer_products AS RP 
LEFT JOIN groups G ON RP.id=G.retailer_product_id AND G.active=1
INNER JOIN products P ON P.id=RP.product_id 
WHERE (RP.product_id IN (1)) 
GROUP BY RP.id;
```